# Is there any layer for nearest-neighbor subsampling label image in caffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I want to subsample the label image in the network, and I wish the output values of the layer are all existed in the input label image (i.e. nearest-neighbor subsampling, while bilinear subsampling does not). How to realize such a layer in caffe? Or where can I find the code for this layer in existed open-source code?
To the best of my knowledge, the **interp** layer in `deeplab` code can realize bilinear subsampling, while the subsampled label image contain illegal labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only after subsampling the label-image at integer intervals, you can use `stride` of a convolution layer:

```
layer {
  name: "sub-sample"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "sub-sample"
  param { lr_mult: 0 decay_mult: 0 }  # do not learn this layer
  convolution_param {
    kernel_size: 1
    pad: 0
    stride: 2  # sub sample by 2
    bias_term: false  # no need for bias
    weight_filler { type: "constant" value: 1 }  
    num_output: 1  # make it the SAME as input number of channels
    group: 1       # same as num_output
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about [pooling layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/pooling.html)? You have Max and Stochastic pooling methods, no nearest neighbor, but it fits your need for the output values to appear in the original input.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. That prevents them from being deleted automatically.

Comment: @BDL why off-topic? this is a good question.

Comment: "Where can I find the code?" is imho asking for a off-site resource.

Comment: @DBL I agree that the phrasing is not optimal, but it is not a general "give-me-the-code" question, but rather "what function of [tag:caffe] I can use to do X-Y-Z". Considering the poor state of [tag:caffe] documentation, this is a legitimate question, IMHO.